# C++ to Java Code Conversion doubts

Tags: java, c++, bit

I am Converting some code from c++ to Java. Having the following doubts-

1. C++ - static char **gprs; 
   In Java - private static String[] gprs; OR private static Byte[] gprs;
2. C++ - static char *mask;
   In Java - private static byte mask; (Correct?)
3. C++ - memset((char *)&rm,'\0',sizeof(DRMK)); //
   Here DRMK is a struct. rm is a object of DRMK. 
   So In java I have to create a class and while declaring the variables I have to set the individual value to 0. Is that Correct?
4. C++ - memcpy (&wp, (PMSK *)p_msk + (long)(x - 1), sizeof(PMSK));
   How to mirror this in Java. PMSK is a struct here.
   And where - static PMSK wp;
           PMSK *pm; 
           static char *p_msk;

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C++ - static char **gprs;
```

Depends on the use of gprs, but I would say (from looking at the rest of the code) that `byte` is more suitable. A byte array that is.

```
C++ - static char *mask;
```

I would use a byte rather than a char given the "mask" name.

```
C++ - memset((char *)&rm,'\0',sizeof(DRMK));
```

As stated in other answers... need to just create a new DRMK instance.

```
C++ - memcpy (&wp, (PMSK *)p_msk + (long)(x - 1), sizeof(PMSK));
```

This is a bitwise mask if you ask me. The value of `wp` will be whatever is at the memory location of (x-1) bytes from the start of `p_msk`. Basically it will copy a chunk of memory of size `sizeof(PMSK)` starting at p_msk+(x-1) into wp.
How to do that in Java? You guessed it... byte array.

Answer (score 2):

1. `private static String[] gprs;`
2. `private static String;` // you're willing to have a string here, but I'm not absolutely sure - depends on the context.
3. Simply `rm = new DRMK();`
4. This depends on the structure of PMSK structure. You should write a method, which semantically does some data copying from a String to the object.

Comment: Yes for both 1,2 the data stored in char gprs is hexadecimal. So I thought Byte will be more appropriate as later there will be logical OR/AND operation on them

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on what `gprs` is being used for.  There's no
   automatic solution.  But if it's characters, `String[]`
   seems more appropriate.
2. Again, it depends on how `mask` is being used; either
   `Byte[]` or `String[]`.
3. You don't need anything.  Java automatically sets all member
   variables to 0, `null` or the moral equivalent before
   calling the constructor.
4. If I understand the code correctly, you need to provide
   a copy constructor for the Java class, and invoke it.

Comment: I would use `byte` instead of `Byte`